# How to examine a core file generated when program is running under valgrind

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind, symbols, core-file

I have a program `myprog` which I have been running under valgrind:

```
/usr/bin/valgrind --tool=massif --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes --log-file=/tmp/valgrind%p /opt/bin/myprog
```

I'm not exactly sure of the details of how valgrind works under the covers, but when run in this manner I see that `valgrind` has a pid, but `myprog` does not.  Thus I assume valgrind runs `myprog` in the same process space and uses some magic to load the target program.

`myprog` appears to have hit an `assert()` and a corefile has been generated.  I would like to examine this corefile using GDB so I can dig into the cause of the `assert()`.  I'm trying to figure out how to load symbols from myprog necessary to use GDB.

If I use `file valgrind`, then this just loads valgrind symbols and nothing from `myprog`

If I use `file myprog`, then the corefile (generated by valgrind) won't match the executable (myprog).

Is there some way I can tell GDB that even though the "host" process here is `valgrind`, that we also want to load the `myprog` symbols, as this is the program we are actually interested in?

Looking through the [GDB documentation](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_14.html), I'm guessing that I'd need something like `add-symbol-file filename address`, but I'm not sure how to figure out what the address would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out how to load symbols from myprog necessary to use GDB.

The usual way: `gdb ./myprog vgcore.1234`.

> If I use `file myprog`, then the corefile (generated by valgrind) won't match the executable (myprog).

It *should* match. Either you are doing something wrong (do tell *exactly* what you are doing), or you have a bug in `valgrind` or `gdb`.

Example:

```
$ cat foo.c
int foo() { abort(); }
int bar() { return foo(); }
int main() { return bar(); }

$ gcc -g -w foo.c
$ valgrind ./a.out

==84263== Using Valgrind-3.9.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==84263== Command: ./a.out
==84263==
==84263==
==84263== HEAP SUMMARY:
==84263==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==84263==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
...

$ ls -lrt
total 2116
-rw-r----- 1 er eng      80 Dec 15 20:18 foo.c
-rwxr-x--- 1 er eng    9558 Dec 15 20:21 a.out
-rw------- 1 er eng 4243434 Dec 15 20:21 vgcore.84263

$ gdb -q ./a.out vgcore.84263    
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
[New LWP 84263]
Core was generated by `'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x0000000004a5bc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000004a5bc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x0000000004a5f028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x0000000000400536 in foo () at foo.c:1
#3  0x0000000000400544 in bar () at foo.c:2
#4  0x0000000000400554 in main () at foo.c:3
```

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.  I get the same results as you with a similar simple test executable under Ubuntu.  Unfortunately the system I have is a proprietary embedded (Linux-based) system with funny GDB wrappers and some extra bells and whistles for its coredumper facility.  I'll have to dig into that more...

Comment: Note that you might also debug your application running under Valgrind, using gdb+vgdb (see http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver). A side note: you specified 2 tools on the command line, only one will really be activated.

Comment: I think this answer is not helpful and provided example works only because it does not employ the same options as OP does.